# Reporting progress from Async Task

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, task

Hello fellow developers,

I am facing a slight dilemma. I have a WPF application that reads an rather large Excel File and after that it outputs it as an XML file. The problem that I am facing is that I want to report the progress of the operation back to the handler.

I cannot get it to work "smoothly", literally the Progress Bar that is in the GUI Thread gets filled at once and immediately after that the DataGrid that holds the content read from the Excel File gets filled.

I am new to Async/Await/Task, I've been using BackgroundWorker until now but I wish to gain more knowledge about this, so I'm sorry if this is a dumb question.

I have read the tutorial from Stephen Cleary from [here.](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/reporting-progress-from-async-tasks.html)

I honestly have no idea why the Progress Bar does not fill "smoothly" as it should be...

Code that is getting called in the GUI:

```
        var progress = new Progress<int>(progressPercent => pBar.Value = progressPercent);

        Task.Run(() => _sourceService.ReadFileContent(filePath, progress)).ContinueWith(task =>
        {

            dataGrid.ItemsSource = task.Result.DefaultView;
            DataTable = task.Result;

            if (DataTable.Rows.Count > 0)
                BtnCreateXmlFile.IsEnabled = true;

        }, CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

The method body of `ReadFileContent(filePath, progress)`:

```
public DataTable ReadFileContent(string filePath, IProgress<int> progress)
    {
        var rowStart = 7;
        var columnStart = 1;

        var existingFile = new FileInfo(filePath);
        using (var package = new ExcelPackage(existingFile))
        {
            var worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets["BOP"];
            var dt = new DataTable();

            // Compose the name of the table from:
            // - Product Type
            // - Customer
            // - Customer Project
            // * These can be found in the "CollaborationContext" sheet that is present in the ExcelFile.
            if (package.Workbook.Worksheets["CollaborationContext"].SelectedRange["B6"].Value.Equals("object_type"))
            {
                dt.TableName = package.Workbook.Worksheets["CollaborationContext"].SelectedRange["C9"].Value + " " +
                               package.Workbook.Worksheets["CollaborationContext"].SelectedRange["D9"].Value + " " +
                               package.Workbook.Worksheets["CollaborationContext"].SelectedRange["E9"].Value;
            }


                dt.TableName = package.Workbook.Worksheets["CollaborationContext"].SelectedRange["B9"].Value + " " + 
                               package.Workbook.Worksheets["CollaborationContext"].SelectedRange["C9"].Value + " " +
                               package.Workbook.Worksheets["CollaborationContext"].SelectedRange["D9"].Value;


            // Report only in chunks. We do not want to call `progress.Report` for each row that is read.
            var totalRows = worksheet.Dimension.End.Row;
            var currentIndex = 0;
            var percentageProgress = totalRows / 10;


            // Get Columns and add them to the DataTable
            for (var col = columnStart; col <= worksheet.Dimension.End.Column - 1; col++)
                dt.Columns.Add(worksheet.Cells[6, col].Value.ToString());

            // Place data into DataTable
            for (var row = rowStart; row <= worksheet.Dimension.End.Row; row++)
            {
                var dr = dt.NewRow();
                var x = 0;
                currentIndex++;

                for (var col = columnStart; col <= worksheet.Dimension.End.Column - 1; col++)
                {
                    dr[x++] = worksheet.Cells[row, col].Value;
                }
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);

                // Report progress back to the handler
                if (currentIndex % percentageProgress == 0)
                    progress?.Report(row);
            }

            return dt;
        } 

    }
```

Thank you in advance !

Comment: How many rows are in the Excel file?  The progress bar will read 100 as soon as you hit the 100th row, because that's the number you're reporting in `progress?.Report()`.  Or something like that.  I don't really get the `if (currentIndex % percentageProgress == 0)`, but maybe I just need to read more carefully.

Comment: Hello, there are 805 rows which are read. Oh wait, do I have to set the Max Value for the progress bar to be above the total number of rows ?!

Comment: That's up to you.  If you don't want to do that, you could report a percentage rather than a row index.

Comment: You are perfectly right, I noticed that I am passing the `row` to the ReportProgress method. The thing is, how do I find out the percentage, I tried doing that with: ` if (currentIndex % percentageProgress == 0)
                    progress?.Report(row);`

Comment: 1) you should be `await`ing that task you are creating 2) you should avoid `Task.Run()` when the job is going to be I/O-bound 3) your progress `pBar.Value = progressPercent` delegate  is not being executed on the UI thread so it won't update

Comment: @MickyD, it is getting hit. When the `report?.Report(row)` is hit, the `pBar.Value = progessPercent` is also called, at least with Debug on.

Comment: @darksleep I'm saying that even though that code executes, it **won't** cause the UI to be updated.  All UI updates **must** be on the UI thread.   When you are debugging your code, take note of the current _thread_

Comment: @MickyD, if I set the breakpoint on `pBar.Value = progessPercent`, in the Threads Window it says that I'm on the MainThread. When `report?.Report(row)` is hit it is on a WorkerThread. Uhm..

Comment: Divide the big tasks to a few smaller tasks and then you can update progress in between.

Comment: @MickyD - Breakpoint set on `progress?.Report(row);` - it shows: `Not Flagged > 2644 12 Worker Thread Worker Thread TeamCenterExport.exe!TeamCenterExport.Service.ExcelSourceService.ReadFileContent Normal
`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If it's not a big trouble. May I ask for an example ?

Comment: Tried to mark the ` ReadFileContent(string filePath, IProgress<int> progress)` with `async` and return a `Task<DataTable>` and call it from the GUI Thread with `var test = await _sourceService.ReadFileContent(filePath, progress)` but with no success. :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, let's get rid of the dangerous `ContinueWith` call. You really should use `await` instead:

```
var progress = new Progress<int>(progressPercent => pBar.Value = progressPercent);
var result = await Task.Run(() => _sourceService.ReadFileContent(filePath, progress));
dataGrid.ItemsSource = result.DefaultView;
DataTable = result;
if (DataTable.Rows.Count > 0)
  BtnCreateXmlFile.IsEnabled = true;
```

Next, the problem you're likely seeing with progress is that your `Progress<int>` handler is expecting a `progressPercent`, but `ReadFileContent` is sending how many rows it's read, *not* a percentage. So, to fix that:

```
if (currentIndex % percentageProgress == 0)
  progress?.Report(row * 100 / totalRows);
```

(there are several other options here; e.g., you could decide to report the current row *and* the total rows if you want a fancier UI).

> the Progress Bar does not fill "smoothly" as it should be

What I've described above is the minimum acceptable solution. In particular, the "only update 10 times" code is a bit problematic; it always updates 10 times, regardless of how fast or slow the updates are. A more general solution would be to use an Rx-based `IProgress` solution, which would allow you to throttle based on time (e.g., 4 updates per second).

Comment: marked as answer. I have modified the code as you posted and it works now. I have modified also the `progress?.Report()` method so it returns the percentage to the progress bar back in the UI Thread. The thing is that I really need to read your blog articles about Async / Await / Task.Run etc. Do you have a starting point which I can iterate through all articles ?

Comment: @darksleep: Not all of them, no. For `async`/`await`, I recommend starting [here](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html), and for `Task.Run`, I recommend starting [here](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/taskrun-etiquette-and-proper-usage.html).

Comment: one more question. I understood that if I call Task.Run(()=>DoSomething()) a thread from the thread pool will be requested to do the job. What's the difference then if I have a method just like the one above and I mark the Event Handler - Button1_Click() with async and within the body I just call `await ReadContentFile()`. With no Task.Run(), no nothing.

Comment: @darksleep: That would work fine, assuming you also change `ReadContentFile` to be an asynchronous method.

Comment: So that means that I would have to mark the `ReadContentFile` as `async` and somehow mark the long running operation with `await`. In this particulare case I would not have what to mark with `await` since it's a basically the whole method is a `for-loop` that reads the content of the Excel File ? In other words, if I would call `await` on the method and the method would not be marked as `async`, basically it would run synchronously ?

Comment: @darksleep: You should approach `async` from the other direction. Start with the lowest-level APIs and make them asynchronous if possible.