# How can I get a progress report on a async function with many tasks, in which I am using await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, maui, progress

I already read all those posts:

[Reporting progress from Async Task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41961070/reporting-progress-from-async-task)

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis/

https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/reporting-progress-from-async-tasks.html

But still I don't know how to report a Progress from many Tasks when I'm using `await Task.WhenAll(tasks);`

So, I am using this code:

```
public string StatusMessage { get; set; }
public async void ButtonClickHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var tasks = new List<Task>
    {
        Task1,
        Task2,
        Task3,
        Task4,
        Task5
    };
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

So I want to get a change in `StatusMessage` when any on `Task1..Task5` is completed. Somehow each task has to have a name and that name to be reported to `StatusMessage` variable.

I want also an event to rise when `StatusMessage` changes.

`StatusMessage` could be also a cumulative list or barely a string.

JSteward post from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48299412/reporting-progress-from-tasks) it is interesting but I don't know how to convert my Task1..Task5 tasks in a `WorkItem` from his sample.

How can I do that?

Comment: Are you sure that this progress behavior will be useful to the user? All the tasks `Task1`, `Task2`, `Task3`, `Task4` and `Task5` might complete roughly at the same time. In other words it seems that you want to report task completion, not progress. My understanding is that progress is supposed to be reported in terms of a number 0 - 100.

Comment: What is the type of the application? WinForms? ASP.NET?

Comment: Try adding `.ContinueWith(() => StatusMessage = "Task X done")` to each entry in the list.

Comment: @Theodor Zoulias
It's a MAUI application. I want to syncronize some tables from central database with sqlite dayabase. I want to send those informations to a label from the splash screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could define an extension method on the `Task` type, that reports progress on an [`IProgress<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iprogress-1) when the task completes successfully:

```
public static async Task OnSuccessfulCompletion<T>(
    this Task task, IProgress<T> progress, T progressValue)
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(task);
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(progress);

    await task.ConfigureAwait(false);
    progress.Report(progressValue);
}
```

And use it like this:

```
public async void ButtonClickHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    /* Launching the tasks Task1, Task2 etc is omitted */
    Progress<string> progress = new(value => textBox1.AppendText($"{value}\r\n"));
    List<Task> tasks = new()
    {
        Task1.OnSuccessfulCompletion(progress, "Task1"),
        Task2.OnSuccessfulCompletion(progress, "Task2"),
        Task3.OnSuccessfulCompletion(progress, "Task3"),
        Task4.OnSuccessfulCompletion(progress, "Task4"),
        Task5.OnSuccessfulCompletion(progress, "Task5"),
    };
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

Be aware that the [`Progress<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.progress-1) type reports progress *asynchronously*. This means that the `handler` might be invoked *after* the completion of the `ButtonClickHandler` method. If you write anything directly on the `textBox1`, immediately after the line `await Task.WhenAll(tasks);`, this text might not be the last to be appended to the `textBox1`. In case you don't like this behavior, you can find a synchronous `IProgress<T>` implementation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59777719/using-taskcompletionsource-within-an-await-task-run-call/59786280#59786280).

Comment: That `Progress<T>` problem should only be faced when you block async code which you should not do anyway

Comment: @SirRufo check out [this demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/iBGret). Using the `Progress<T>`, the message `"Done"` appears before the messages reported by the `progress`, which might not be desirable. Using the `SynchronousProgress<T>`, the `"Done"` appears last as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The standard `IProgress<T>` is a bit limiting if you want to do more detailed progress reporting. There is no easy way to include features like description or to distribute the work over multiple independent tasks.

My preference is to replace this with a custom progress class, something like

```
public class Progress
{
    // object should *either* have value+description, *or* subProgress list
    private double value;
    private string description = "";
    private Progress[] subProgress;

    // progress should always be between 0-1 to keep math simple
    public double Value
    {
        get
        {
            var subProgressLocal = subProgress;
            if (subProgress != null)
            {
                return subProgressLocal.Sum(s => s.Value ) / subProgressLocal.Length;
            }

            return value;
        }
    }

    public string Description
    {
        get
        {
            var subProgressLocal = subProgress;
            if (subProgressLocal != null)
            {
                return subProgressLocal.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Value is > 0d and < 1d)?.Description ?? "";
            }

            return description;
        }
    }

    public Progress[] CreateSubProgress(int count)
    {
        if (subProgress != null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Can only create sub-progresses once");
        subProgress = Enumerable.Range(0, count).Select(_ => new Progress()).ToArray();
        return subProgress;
    }

    // progress should always be between 0-1 to keep math simple
    public void Report(double progress, string description = "")
    {
        if (subProgress != null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot report progress when using sub-progress");
        // Clamp to 0-1 range
        this.value = progress < 0 ? 0 : (progress > 1 ? 1 : progress);
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

This allow you to build a "tree" that matches the computations you are doing, where all reporting is done on the leaf nodes. So you can have multiple nested loops while still getting detailed progress reporting, and without needing to know the total amount of work before you start.

This does not raise any event on the UI thread when a task reports progress. So you will need to use a UI compatible timer to periodically poll the progress and update the UI. Also note that this is not strictly thread safe, since shared variables will be read and written to from different threads, but the worst that could happen should be a slightly lagging progress bar. Also note that this is a "one time use"-object, create a new one each time you need progress reporting.

Usage like:

```
void DoMultiStepWork(Progress p){
    var subprogress = p.CreateSubProgress(3);
    DoPart1(subProgress[0]);
    DoPart2(subProgress[1]);
    DoPart3(subProgress[2]);
}
void DoPart1(Progress p){
    for(int i = 0; i < myCollection.Count; i++){
       // do work
       p.Report(i / (double)myCollection.Count, myCollection[i].Name);
    }
}
```

You can write extension methods to make usage more convenient, like `foreach(var item in myCollection.ProgressReporting(p))`. Or add features like weights for each sub-progress, to handle cases with uneven work distribution.

This should work even if each method is run on different tasks or threads.